# Change the values of a dataframe, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Case statement inside the data frame, what am I doing wrong here?

```
df1['Response'] = [4 if x =='Closed with monetary relief' 
               3 if x =='Closed with non-monetary relief'
               2 if x =='Closed with explanation' 
               1 if x =='Closed' 
               0 if x =='Untimely response' for x in df1['Response']]
```

Error I see:

> 3 if x =='Closed with non-monetary relief'
>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please share the entirety of your program, or at least the relevant area(s). There are probably other unidiomatic choices which could complicate things. That is incorrect syntax anyway, regardless of whether or not it would be idiomatic Pandas.

Comment: Such approach would be highly inefficient for large dataframes, it is better to use pandas built in functions as @jezrael suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is best use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary:

```
d = {'Closed with monetary relief' : 4,
     'Closed with non-monetary relief':3.
     'Closed with explanation':2,
     'Closed':1,
     'Untimely response':0}

df1['Response'] = df1['Response'].map(d)
```

If some value not match get missing value, you can replace it by original:

```
df1['Response'] = df1['Response'].map(d).fillna(df1['Response'])
```

Or by some another value e.g. `-1`, then also convert values to integers, because at least one `NaN` create `float`s column:

```
df1['Response'] = df1['Response'].map(d).fillna(-1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Why is the `astype(int)` necessary?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - yop, because at least one NaN convert values to floats, so necessary.

Comment: Ah that’s true, NaN is a float!

Comment: I’m keeping you on your toes ;) Wouldn’t want you to get too comfortable :p Although idk if this last one was a good question. I was probably distracted and didn’t think it through.

Answer (score 1):

Try this format, it should work:

```
df1.Response.apply(lambda x: 4 if x =='Closed with monetary relief' else
               3 if x =='Closed with non-monetary relief' else
               2 if x =='Closed with explanation' else
               1 if x =='Closed' else
               0 if x =='Untimely response' else None )
```